# Difficult sentence in Nicomachean ethics by Aristotle

Tags: grammar, phrases

I am translating Aristotle' Nicomachean ethics into Vietnamese from the English translation done by J. A. Smith (Project Gutenberg). In Book VII of the work I came across a sentence which has proven incomprehensible to me. That is

> Now   a man may raise a question as to the nature of the right
>   conception    in violation of which a man fails of Self-Control.

I've refered to other interpretations as well and now I'm clear of what this line means. However, I still need to be sure about the structure of this sentence. Is this a relative clause with "of which"? If so, what does "which" here replace? 
Also, can somebody clarify the phrase "conception in violation"?

Comment: *which* <-- "conception". Read it as "the right conception, in violation of which a man fails ...." with a comma after the noun phrase to help parse. HTH.

Comment: Not sure if the above technically qualifies as an answer, which is why it's a comment for now.

Comment: the original at wikisource https://el.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%97%CE%B8%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC_%CE%9D%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%AC%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1

Comment: the antecedent of _which_ is _conception_

Comment: in violation of the conception

Comment: _in violation of which ..._ is a relative clause

Comment: the nature of the right conception in violation of which a man fails of Self-Control.= if a man violates the nature of the right conception he falls short of self-control (fails to control himself); the difficult term there is: right conception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should undoubtedly be a comma after *conception*, which would make it clearer that the clause from then onwards is a definition or explanation of *the right conception*.
(Expansion of Kris's comment).

I also feel constrained to point out that if you are translating Aristotle, who is a founder of Western philosophy but whose language is not straightforward, you really need to do it from the Greek. Working from a Gutenberg translation into English risks falling into [English As She Is Spoke](https://publicdomainreview.org/collections/english-as-she-is-spoke-1884/).

Comment: that this gets two downvotes, and presumably no upvotes, shows how hopelessly stupid this site is

Comment: The 20th century follow-up (1988) to that was: The Cow Went to the Swamp.:)

Comment: I downvoted as by implying that a translation from the English is useless and then requiring the questioner to learn Ancient Greek is a bit much.

Answer (score 2):

Some words are used in unusual meanings and require clarification:

OED:

> **Conception:** II 5 c c. Philosophy. **The action** or faculty **of grasping** or creating **a** general idea or **concept**.
>
> 1818   S. T. Coleridge Gen. Introd. or Treat. on Method 10 in Encycl. Metrop. I   There are many marked differences between mathematical and physical studies; but in both a previous act and conception of the mind..is indispensably necessary.
>
> 1903   Mind 12 32   A diagram can only serve as an aid to mental conception; it does not directly show forth the real order.
>
> 2011   F. C. Beiser German Historicist Trad. iv. 189   He wields his powers of conception, which grasp all these details into a meaningful whole.
>
> II. **To fail of**:To have a deficiency or want; to lack.
>
> 6. b. **to fail of:** = **7. [See below]**
>
> 1671   R. Bohun Disc. Wind 20   When the Atmosphere begins to thicken..wee seldom fail of a Wind.
>
> 1796   J. Morse Amer. Universal Geogr. (new ed.) I. 150   Whenever the continent shall come to fail of timber.
>
> **7. transitive. To be or become deficient in; to lack, want, be without. *Now rare*.**
>
> 1869   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest III. xi. 45   The Primate prayed that their chosen King might never fail the throne.

*Now a man may raise a question as to the nature of the right conception in violation of which a man fails of Self-Control.*

Of course, it is possible that someone might ask about the nature of “grasping the right concept”, and if they do not “grasping the right concept”, then they will lack self control.

Comment: Second "grasping" should perhaps be grasp

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the source material or context, I'd interpret it as:

> Now a man may raise a question

A person might ask...

> as to the nature of the right conception

...about right conception's nature...

> in violation of which a man fails of Self-Control.

...when a person lacks self-control.

Depending on context, there could be a few other ways to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

> Now a man may raise a question as to the nature of the right
>   conception in violation of which a man fails of Self-Control.

An attempted rewording:

> There exists some general principle (a "right conception"), which, if
>   violated, means that one lacks Self-Control. One may raise a question
>   about the nature of this principle.

I'm stretching a bit for a better wording for "right conception," but my guess is that it may have been translated somewhat over-literally from something like "correct idea."

Comment: The 'right conception' _may well_ be 'accepted moral standards'. "What _are_ the rules one lapses/sins [V intrans] if one doesn't adhere to?" But this is probably the best attempt. However, comprehension questions become off-topic when individual words / constructions are not specified by OP, _singly_. So mis-parsing (in the question) needs correcting (in the question) first.